# How do I check, at user logon, if a Firefox plugin exists?

Tags: firefox, scripting, powershell, windows-xp

I want to check if the users on our domain have a certain Firefox plugin installed. Maybe we can have a script that *checks if the folders created by the plugin exist*. And if not raise some sort of alert to the user.

An example of the plugin folder is below. There are randomly generated parts that will probably make it more complicated.

> C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles{random}.{profile name (“default”)}\ {random-id}@jetpack\resources{same random-id}-at-jetpack-pluginname-data\

---

1. I have NO clue about Windows scripting, this is the first time I'm even thinking about it
2. This question is a bit of a "please do it for me" because of 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some PowerShell that will search the `appdata` directory for all folders containing that special plugin name. On error, you should alert the user and force them to interact with the alert (the `Read-Host`). When they continue, you can launch Firefox directly to the installer page.

```
if(-not(Get-ChildItem "$env:appdata\Mozilla\Firefox" -recurse -include "*@jetpack" | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }))
{
    Read-Host "The Firefox 'jetpack' plugin was not found. You will be redirected to the plugin page now. Please install the 'jetpack' plugin. (press any key to continue)"
    & 'path\to\firefox.exe' 'http:\\path.to.plugin.com'
}
```

The output on the console should look something like

```
The Firefox 'jetpack' plugin was not found. You will be redirected to the plugin page now. Please install the 'jetpack' plugin. (press any key to continue):
```

Comment: A bit on the technical side, but I'm ok with it. Great idea to launch Firefox to the installer straight away, did not even think about that possibility.

Comment: I would definitely drop the `Write-Error`, print something friendly in the `Read-Host` (forcing the user to respond to the alert), and launch firefox (I updated the answer). I assume you're already familiar with the places to put scripts to get them to run at [startup](http://goo.gl/NWCeE)?

Answer (score 1):

Is this possible?  Definitely.  I'm not sure the best method, but I'll attack this from the PowerShell angle.

It might be difficult to use PowerShell because you need to verify that everyone has PowerShell installed.  If you can verify that, it's a pretty simple request.

Use

```
$firefoxfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path ($env:appdata + "\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles") -Recurse
```

This will give you a list of all the files in that directory... treat all of the code in this answer as an example, you'll certainly have to change it.

```
if (!($firefoxfiles | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "PluginFileName"} ) {
...code for pop up...}
```

There's a ton of samples out there for an error dialog from PowerShell.

Good luck!